# Google Map fragment on driver's side refreshes when customer ends ride, and I lose all data. Any suggestions, please?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

PS: When I delete a CustomersPicked straight from Firebase, the map doesn't reload.
I'm creating an app for car pooling. When the customer ends the ride, the Google map fragment reloads and my activity loses data. I'm also using a Firebase RecyclerView.

I tried editing my end ride function, debugging etc...
I also changed valueEventListeners to ListenerForSingleValueEvents.
The sequence is:
 the driver sets his destination and clicks a switch to show he is available, the rider can see that on his map, if he sets the same direction.

at the bus stop when the driver picks the rider, the rider scans his qr and then get added to his CustomerPicked table, which triggers the RecyclerView, to show the user.
My problem is: when the user ends the ride, the driver activity and map reloads.

CustomerMap Activty:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_costumer_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is //ready to be used.
    context = this;
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    init();
}



private int radius = 1;
private Boolean driverFound = false;
private String driverFoundID;

GeoQuery geoQuery;
//used to pick the closest driver
private void getClosestDriver(){
    DatabaseReference driverLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("driversWorking").child(destination);

    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverLocation);
    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLongitude(), mLastLocation.getLatitude()), radius);
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();

    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            if (!driverFound){
                DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(key);
                mCustomerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                            if (driverFound){
                                return;
                            }

                            if(!driverFound){
                                driverFound = true;
                                driverFoundID = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                                getDriverLocation();
                                //getDriverInfo();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Looking for Driver Location....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            if (!driverFound)
            {
                radius++;
                getClosestDriver();
            }
        }


    });
}





    ****private void endRide(){
    recordRide();
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    dest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    destinationTextview.setText("Welcome to Sole");
    driverFound = false;
    radius = 1;
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference refq = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customerPicked").child(driverFoundID).child(userId);
    refq.removeValue();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversWorking").child(destination).child("customerRequest");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    geoFire.removeLocation(userId);
    if (mDriverMarker != null){
        mDriverMarker.remove();
    }
    if (rideDistance > 0){
        rideDistance = 0;
    }
}****





@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.style_json)));

    if (!success) {
        Log.e("styling", "Style parsing failed.");
    }

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }else{
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

}
LatLng latLng;
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for(Location location : locationResult.getLocations()){
            if(getApplicationContext()!=null){
                mLastLocation = location;

                if (onTrip && mLastLocation != null && location != null) {
                    rideDistance += mLastLocation.distanceTo(location) / 1000;
                }

                latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

DriverMap activity

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map);
    context = this;

    //location services
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    init();

        }
    };
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
     manager = new LinearLayoutManager(DriverMapActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    recyclerAdapter.startListening();
}


@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    recyclerAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    recyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.style_json)));

    if (!success) {
        Log.e("styling", "Style parsing failed.");
    }
}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            if (getApplicationContext() != null) {
                mLastLocation = location;

                latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
                if(connect && driver_destination!= "") {
                    //sets the driver as working when he switches on
                    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference refWorking2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversWorking").child(driver_destination);
                    GeoFire geoFireWorking = new GeoFire(refWorking2);
                    geoFireWorking.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

}

When my end ride runs on my customer activity, it remotely restarts the driver, here's the driver log

````
05-21 13:15:33.247 9159-10290/com.aderoju.sole D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7f47fbdac8
05-21 13:15:33.247 9159-10290/com.aderoju.sole D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7f47fbdac8
05-21 13:15:33.267 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.aderoju.sole-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.aderoju.sole rsrc of package com.aderoju.sole
05-21 13:15:33.287 9159-14446/com.aderoju.sole D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=378069, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=DriverMapActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3114034998008447800}]
05-21 13:15:33.287 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 17122019
05-21 13:15:33.377 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-21 13:15:33.397 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/ClipboardExManager: no knox
05-21 13:15:33.397 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.397 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment isFragment :true
05-21 13:15:33.397 9159-10263/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:33.397 9159-10263/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:33.397 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole I/Switch: Immediately mode attached=false laidOut=false
05-21 13:15:33.397 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole I/Switch: Immediately mode attached=false laidOut=false
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-10265/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-10265/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.407 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.417 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.417 9159-10263/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 20 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 9159, getuid(): 10171
05-21 13:15:33.417 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
05-21 13:15:33.417 9159-10265/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 70 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 9159, getuid(): 10171
05-21 13:15:33.427 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
05-21 13:15:33.427 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.aderoju.sole.DriverMapActivity isFragment :false
05-21 13:15:33.427 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
05-21 13:15:33.427 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{29fe9e I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
05-21 13:15:33.427 9159-14446/com.aderoju.sole D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=DriverMapActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-3114034998008447800, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=DriverMapActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3114034998008447799}]
05-21 13:15:33.467 9159-9250/com.aderoju.sole D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
05-21 13:15:33.487 9159-14452/com.aderoju.sole D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f466a7f08
05-21 13:15:33.487 9159-14452/com.aderoju.sole D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2476]-format:2
05-21 13:15:33.507 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 0) or=1
05-21 13:15:33.537 9159-14446/com.aderoju.sole D/FA: Connected to remote service
05-21 13:15:33.537 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7fe15ff528
05-21 13:15:33.577 9159-9159/com.aderoju.sole I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@408b32e time:13317841
05-21 13:15:33.577 9159-10264/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:33.577 9159-10264/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:33.577 9159-10264/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 49 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 9159, getuid(): 10171
05-21 13:15:33.797 9159-9250/com.aderoju.sole D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f6552ef08
05-21 13:15:34.307 9159-10265/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 128 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 9159, getuid(): 10171
05-21 13:15:34.307 9159-10264/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 129 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 9159, getuid(): 10171
05-21 13:15:34.307 9159-10263/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 131 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 9159, getuid(): 10171
05-21 13:15:34.757 9159-10263/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 20
05-21 13:15:34.757 9159-10265/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 70
05-21 13:15:35.777 9159-10264/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 49
05-21 13:15:35.887 9159-9250/com.aderoju.sole D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f6552ef08
05-21 13:15:35.957 9159-9250/com.aderoju.sole D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f6552ef08
05-21 13:15:36.487 9159-10262/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:36.497 9159-10262/com.aderoju.sole I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-21 13:15:36.517 9159-10262/com.aderoju.sole I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 104 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 9159, getuid(): 10171
```
````

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than 700 lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online.

Comment: i've tried to delete more codes, the problem is i don't know where it's coming from, i only know that when the endRide function runs, my map on both activity refreshes and loses data. since i can't pinpoint, it's causing more stress, apologies .

Comment: @mamo i have updated it, i believe this is better, any help will be appreciated

Comment: @gboyegaAderoju that stack-trace is irrelevant... maybe iron out the flawed business logic with a piece of paper & a pen. adding verbose logging might also help to produce rather meaningful logs. it might be the `refq.removeValue()`... what does it actually do? trigger a child remove event on the driver side?

Comment: refq is removes the value being listened to by `Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customerPicked").child(driverId);
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setQuery(query, User.class)
                .build();` i'm using this query for my Firebase Recycler Adapter